# Nopcommerce API Information

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0, nopcommerce-4.3

I am planning to replace conventional checkout process of nopcommerce with nopcommerce API. Does Nopcommerce provide the Checkout process with this nopcommerce API ?
Please help me if there is any resource link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nopcommerce API only provides API endpoint for single page apps Or mobile apps.

If you want to create a custom checkout process using Nopcommerce API, You need to extend the API plugin

Or, You can create a new plugin

Or, You can customize the theme -> checkout -> index page in a way that will send requests to Nopcommerce API and progress the checkout to the confirmation page (like a single page app)